# Booles Rule derivation ( closed Newton cotes formulae)

Tags: numerical-methods

Can anyone show me the derivation of Booles Rule. I've been studying the Closed Newton cotes formula and derived the rules up to degree n=3 Simpsonson Rule 3/8  but would love to see a derivation of Booles Rule. I'm aware it stems from the 3/8 Simpson rule!